# Simple Java form that would send data to webpage?

Tags: java, forms, mobile-application

I know virtually no java, but I need to make a simple java application for mobiles that would display a form.On being submitted The data would then be sent to a webpage. As I am a php programmer, I would prefer to have it sent to a php file, which would then use the form's data. I only need a couple of input text areas, would anybody be able to help me with the java part?
Thanks in advance. 
Niall

Comment: So are you asking for somebody to write your app for you?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what platform but no matter what you choose you will need to look into [HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) and here is a [good example of mimicking a form based submission](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientFormLogin.java).

As far as presenting a form, that's very platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If you can call your PHP File by calling an URL via GET, than you should be able to solve your problem with the following piece of code:

```
int variable1 = 4;
String variable2 = "My Phone Service";
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://myserver.com/service.php?var1=" + variable1 + "&variable2=" + variable2);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()));
    String s = null;
    while((s= reader.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
}
```